# How to write å (danish) in login prompt?

Tags: login, system-language

Running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on a surface laptop 4

Changed password to a string containing `å`.
After restart I cannot type the letter `å` in login prompt.
I have tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> + `00e5`, but that does not work.
When using the visual keyboard I have only US-english available.

Comment: On my keyboard, it's RIGHT ALT + w. Does that work on your keyboard?

Comment: Is the problem that you have 'å' in the username or in the password? Is there only one user, or is there another user (with another unername)?

Comment: I assume you can't type "å" because your keyboard layout has been changed for some reason; if so, perhaps change XKBVARIANT = “dk” on file /etc/default/keyboard

Comment: - Jos does not work for me
- sudodus only one user, å in password
- kurja how to change file when I cant login?

Comment: @DrHyper You can enter root shell from grub boot menu; as here https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Comment: @DrHyper, It should work to create a new password according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password/24024#24024). And this time *use only standard ascii characters* (ascii numbers 33 <--> `!` to 126 <--> `~`) that is `0-9 A-Z a-z` and some special characters (following `!` in the ascii table and for example `_`).