# How to NOT become a root user? Are administrators root?

Tags: sudo, root, users, privileges, administrator

I installed Ubuntu on my PC. To log in, I use the username and password I created during installation. Does this mean I am a root user? If yes, then how do I become non-root? It looks like non-root user is more secure than admin user.

Comment: You are confusing _root_ with _administrator_, two different things.

Comment: Related: [RootSudo (in the Ubuntu wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Comment: Windows 7 does not make this distinction clear, which really bothers and confuses me. The equivalent of running as root in Windows is to "Run as Administrator." But of course, if you're logged in as an administrator, you're already running everything as administrator by definition. Really poor terminology choice.

Comment: @KrisHarper **It isn't *by definition*** (or even true) that users must run programs as themselves. In Ubuntu, administrators (who aren't root) can run programs as root with `sudo`. More generally, an administrator (or otherwise authorized user) X can run `command...` as Y with `sudo -u Y command...`. In Windows Vista and later, with [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) on, users with administrative powers *run programs without them*, except when they explicitly authorize a program inherit their abilities. *Run as Administrator* appears when UAC's on (or for limited users).

Comment: @EliahKagan Of course you are correct. Under the hood users are issued a low-level security token and can request a higher level one when needed. I was speaking semantically from a user-experience standpoint though. If I administrate a computer, and am using it, I am literally running programs as an administrator. My point was that it's a poor terminology choice because it breaks the abstraction between the physical administrator (myself) and the digital one (a specific user account). I find it to be bad UX, even though the technically proficient will understand what is going on.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You are an administrator, but not `root`. The `root` user can do anything. Administrators can [*perform actions as `root`*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), but ordinarily what administrators do is not done by `root`. That way, you have full control over your own system, but only when you *choose* to use it.

Ubuntu asks for your password when you try to do stuff as `root`, to make sure it's really you.

### User Accounts: Human, and Otherwise

Real human users have user accounts to represent them. You created one such account when you installed Ubuntu. But *not all user accounts represent real human users*.

Real human users are granted (and denied) abilities through their user accounts. They must use their user accounts to use the system; therefore, their user accounts' abilities and limitations apply to them.

User accounts are also used to codify sets of abilities and limitations. Some user accounts--most, actually, unless you have *many* human users of the machine--exist so that certain programs or commands can be run with their identity, an identity with the right abilities and limitations for the job.

For example, the `www-data` user exists so that if you run a web server, it owns the data the server make accessible. No real human user has to be empowered to make unchecked changes to those data, and the web server doesn't have to be empowered to perform any action unnecessary for serving the web. Consequently, both the web data and the rest of the system are more secure against accidental or intentional breakage, than if the web server were run by some human user who would have all the powers of the web server (and whose powers the web server would possess).

### The Most Important Non-Human User Account

The [superuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser), whose username is `root`, is a non-human user account with a very specific combination of abilities and limitations: **all abilities, and no limitations**.

<sup>`root`'s *allowed* to do anything. There are still things `root` cannot do because the system itself cannot perform or make sense out of them. So `root` cannot [kill a process that is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/701138/1038860) in [uninterruptible sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223644/what-is-an-uninterruptable-process), or [make a rock too heavy to move, then move it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipotence#Paradoxes).</sup>

Many important system processes, like [`init`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/init.8.html), run as `root`, and `root` is used for performing administrative tasks.

### Can I log in as `root`?

It's possible to configure the `root` account so it's possible to log in with a password, but this is not enabled by default in Ubuntu. Instead, you can think of `root` as being like `www-data`, `lp`, `nobody`, and other non-human accounts. (Run `cat /etc/passwd` or `getent passwd` to see them all.)

Human users log in with their own user accounts, and then if some task is to be performed with another user account, they *cause that task to be performed with that identity*, without actually having *logged in* as that user.

<sup>It's possible to configure the other non-human users, like `www-data`, so one can log in as them, too. That's quite rare, though, whereas in some other Unix-like OSes it's common to log in as `root` *in a terminal*. The risks of running a whole graphical interface as `root`, combined with how many graphical programs are not designed to run as `root` and may not work properly, mean that you should never attempt to get a `root`-owned *desktop session*.</sup>

*Please note that while logging in as `root` is disabled by default in Ubuntu, there are ways to get a `root` shell without authenticating as `root`, which produce a similar effect: the most common are [`sudo -s` or `-i`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1388843), [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) and [similar techniques](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15284/how-to-boot-to-root-shell-when-grub-recovery-menu-fails-to-load-a-shell). (Don't worry if you don't know what those things are.) This is not actually logging in: in recovery mode, you become `root` before any login would occur; with the `sudo`-based methods, you're just running a shell as root.*

### Administrators

In Ubuntu, administrators are the users who can do whatever they want as `root`, *when they choose to do so*.

[image: System Settings, showing human user accounts including an administrator account.]
<sup>**System Settings > User Accounts. "Eliah Kagan" is an administrator, so he can do stuff as `root`, but he *is not `root`*.**</sup>

I'm an administrator on my Ubuntu system. When I run programs, ordinarily they run as `ek` ("Eliah Kagan" is the full name that corresponds to the `ek` username.)

When I run AbiWord or LibreOffice, it runs as `ek`. When I run Firefox, Chromium, Empathy, or Pidgin, it runs as `ek`. The programs that run to provide the desktop interface run as `ek`.

However, I am an administrator, so if I need to perform an administrative task, I can do so.

### sudo

On the command line, I would ordinarily use [`sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/sudo.8.html) to run a command as `root`:

```
sudo command...
```

This will prompt me for *my* password. (Not `root`'s password; `root` does not have one.)

- Because I am an administrator, I can perform actions as `root`. In the default configuration, I must enter my password to do this.
- Users who are not administrators cannot perform actions as `root`, even by putting in their password. `sudo` commands will fail if the user running them is not an administrator.

Because administrators are perfectly ordinary users *except* for the ability to perform actions as `root`, running a command requiring `root` privileges will still fail, except when the command is run *as `root`*.

[image: Screenshot illustrating the need for sudo: an administrator can only run certain commands successfully by doing so as <code>root</code>, which is usually done by prepending sudo (and a space) to the command.]
<sup>**Screenshot illustrating the need to use `sudo` to perform administrative tasks. (Based on ["Sandwich"](http://xkcd.com/149/) by [Randall Munroe](http://xkcd.com/about/).)**</sup>

### sudo, Graphically

Graphical programs can run as `root` through [graphical frontends for `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), such as [`gksu`/`gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksudo.1.html) and [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html). For example, to run GParted as `root` I could run `gksudo gparted`. Then I would be prompted graphically for my password.

[image: gksudo graphical password prompt]

Since I'm prompted graphically, there doesn't have to be a terminal. This is one of the ways administrative tools are run as `root`.

### Polkit

[Polkit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/polkit.8.html) (once known as PolicyKit) is another way for administrators to do things as `root`. A program accesses a service that performs the action. Sometimes, the action is running a whole program; sometimes the action is more limited.

These days, many graphical system administration utilities are set up to use polkit by default, rather than to use `sudo`.

One example of such a utility is the Software Center. It takes full advantage of polkit, requiring the user to put in their password *only* when they want to *do something* that requires `root` privileges. (This is possible with `sudo`-based authentication also, but it is harder and uglier to accomplish.)

In the Software Center, I can find and read about an application; then I'm asked for my password when I want to install it.

[image: Authenticating via polkit to install an application in the Ubuntu Software Center.]

### How polkit Is Different

Any graphical program can be run as `root` with `gksudo` and other graphical `sudo` frontends. (The program might not *work* very well, depending on whether or not it's designed to be used as `root`. But the command to start the program will be executed as `root`.)

While polkit is now more common than `sudo` GUI frontends as the way applications on Ubuntu perform actions as `root` behind the scenes, polki will only run a graphical application as `root` [if there is a configuration file allowing it and indicating what actions may be performed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo).

### Polkit, Non-Graphically

`pkexec` is the command used to run a program with polkit.

Like `sudo`, [`pkexec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/pkexec.1.html) can run non-graphical commands. (And it does not require a configuration file defining the command's capabilities--it simply runs the command as `root`.)

```
pkexec command...
```

`pkexec` prompts for a password graphically, even if it is run from a Terminal (this is one of the ways its behavior is more similar to `gksudo` than to running straight `sudo`).

<sup>(If there is no GUI--for example, if you're logged in from a [virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) or text-only [SSH session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH), or the GUI is not functioning properly--then `pkexec` will [degrade gracefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system) and prompt for your password on the command line.)</sup>

[image: Running a command in a terminal with pkexec.]

Once authentication is performed successfully, the command runs in the terminal.

[image: A command runs seamlessly as <code>root</code> after successfully polkit authentication.]

### Running Commands as Other Users Besides `root`

`root` is special because it gets to do anything that can be done. But it's a user account like any account, and the ways of running commands as `root` with `sudo` (directly or with a graphical frontend) or polkit can be modified slightly to run a command as any other user:

```
sudo -u username command...
```

```
gksudo -u username command...
```

```
pkexec --user username command...
```

### What? You just type `sudo` first? How is that security?!

Running commands with `sudo` is sort of like invoking [papal infalliblity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_infallibility).

**When you *run a command with `sudo`*** [invoke papal infallibility]**, *Ubuntu*** [Catholic folks] **tries hard to make sure you're *really you*** [really the Pope].

<sup>Yes, I know papal infallibility (even when normative) is declarative; the parallel is not perfect.</sup>

Trying to do something as `root` with `sudo` (or polkit) is a big deal--Ubuntu is not just going to let that slide by like all the other times you run a program.

You are prompted for your password. (Then, that you have done so is remembered for a short time, so you don't have to constantly enter your password as you administer your system.)

Besides *reminding you to be careful*, this safeguards against two scenarios:

- Someone uses your computer (or mobile device), maybe under the guise of checking their email or some similar innocuous purpose. Here, it's still possible for them to do some harm--for example, they could modify or delete your documents. However, they cannot administer the system, since they cannot put in your password.
- Programs that aren't supposed to administer the system cannot do so, unless you enter your password. For example, if your web browser is compromised by a security bug and runs malicious code, it still cannot perform administrative tasks. It cannot create and delete users, modify programs installed as `root` (which includes anything installed by the package manager, such as LibreOffice), or alter the system at a deep level.

### I've heard of `su`. What's that? Can I use that?

`su` authenticates as another user, and runs a command (or starts an interactive shell). It's possible to limit *who* is permitted to use `su`, but `su` authenticates with the *target* account's password, not the password of the user running.

For example, `su username -c 'command...'` runs **`command...`** as *username*, just like `sudo -u username command...`.

But when you run a command as *`username`* with `sudo`, you enter **your password**. When you run a command as *`username`* with `su`, you enter ***`username`*'s password**.

Since `su` performs authentication *for the target user*, with `su` you can only run commands as users *whose accounts are enabled*.

The `root` account (like `www-data` and `nobody`) is disabled by default. There is no password that will work to log in as `root`. So you cannot use `su` to run commands as `root`.

You *can* use `su` to run commands as another user who can log in (which typically includes all the user accounts on your system that represent human beings).

When logged in as a guest, you cannot use `su` at all.

#### Combining `su` and `sudo`

Someone who is not an administrator can even use `su` to run `sudo` as an administrator. (This is OK though, as they need the administrator's password to run commands as the administrator.) That is, a limited user can use `su` to run `sudo` to run a command as `root`. This can look like:

```
su username -c 'sudo command...'
```

(Running graphical programs this way [requires special care](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164819/how-can-i-run-an-application-with-a-gui-as-super-user-from-a-normal-user-session).)

### Wouldn't `su` be a more secure way to run commands as `root`?

Probably not.

#### What if a user shouldn't be allowed to act as `root`?

Make them a limited user instead of an administrator.

#### What if a program running as an administrator tries to `sudo` to `root`?

Unless you have reconfigured `sudo` to let it succeed without a password, it will fail.

#### Can't a program that shouldn't be run as `root` piggyback on a recent `sudo` command, so no password is required?

This would be very unlikely to succeed. These days, most operating systems (including Ubuntu) have `sudo` configured by default so that its timestamps apply only in a specific context.

For example, if I run `sudo ...` in one Terminal tab and authenticate successfully, `sudo` in another tab (or run by an unrelated GUI program, or that I run from a virtual console or SSH session) will still prompt for a password. Even if it's run immediately afterwards.

#### Doesn't a program running as user X have access to user X's password?

No.

#### If a malicious program is able to run as an administrator, can't it "listen in" to what's being typed when the administrator authenticates with `sudo` or polkit?

Potentially, yes. But then it could "listen in" to a password typed in for `su`.

#### If I tell someone my password—

Don't tell people your password.

#### What if someone has to know my password to do something on my behalf, but I don't want to let them administer the system?

Ideally, they should have a separate user account that lets them do what they need to do. For example, can share files between accounts, allowing multiple user to write to them, while still denying access to other users.

However, in a situation where a less-trusted person may be permitted to share your account, it should be a limited user account. You could make a separate account for this purpose (which makes sense--if it's an account for you and someone else who you want to have different capabilities, it should be a different account).

#### So, would the most secure thing be to disallow both `sudo` and `su` and make people log in as `root`, manually?

No, because there are serious disadvantages associated with letting people log in as `root` at all. Whenever possible, the smallest number of actions as possible should be undertaken as `root`. Even most acts relating directly to administering a system (e.g., looking at what users are configured, and reading logs) usually don't require `root` privileges.

Also, just as *potentially* a malicious program could watch what someone types when they run `sudo` or `su`, or create a fake `sudo`/`su` password prompt, *potentially* a malicious program could create a fake login screen, too.

### What makes a user an administrator?

[**Group membership.**](https://askubuntu.com/a/174384/22949)

[In Ubuntu 12.04 and later](https://askubuntu.com/a/122500/22949), administrators are members of the group called `sudo`.

[In Ubuntu 11.10 and earlier](https://askubuntu.com/a/43357/22949), administrators are members of the group called `admin`.

When an Ubuntu system before 12.04 is upgraded to 12.04 or later, the `admin` group is kept for backward compatibility (and continues to confer administrative power to users in it), but the `sudo` group is used as well.

### Limited User Accounts

#### Can I use a limited user account instead of an administrator account?

If you like, sure. Create a limited user account in **System Settings** > **User Accounts**, and log in as that user.

#### Can I make my administrator account a limited user account?

Yes, just remove it from the `sudo` and `admin` groups (see above).

**But you should make sure there is at least one other administrator account, so you can administer your system.** If there is not, then [you'd have to boot to recovery mode or a live CD and make some user an administrator again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/170274/what-happens-if-all-users-are-set-as-standard-while-root-password-not-set). (This [is similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/84474/how-can-i-give-admin-permissions-to-my-account/84475#84475) to [resetting a lost administrator password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).)

Graphical tools for administering users and groups will *usually* keep you from creating a system with no administrators, or at least warn you. Command line tools typically will not (trusting that you know what you're doing).

Comment: @EliahKagan-another dumb one :) I will make an analogy - Root is like a parent and any user is like a child. Elder children (admins) have more privileges. A child(user) can never be THE Parent(Root). The 12 year old child can do non-dangerous things in the house (OS/Ubuntu) like use the fridge and stuff. He is not allowed to touch the money in safe. But, the 18 year old (admin) can, using 'sudo' or permission of parent to access that money. But, both are not allowed to touch the gun in another safe. Only root(parent) can do that. Makes sense ?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName Administrator accounts represent real human users who, in the real world, have all the power. Admins can "make `root` do anything" with `sudo` and PolicyKit. An admin could even enable the `root` account and log in. If you abstract a user account as a combination of [mechanistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automaton) and conscious actions, human users have both and non-human users including `root` act purely mechanistically. If you understand how it all works, then if your analogy reinforces that, great! But I don't think it really captures the root-admin relationship.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName It seems to me a better analogy is: administrators are like Bruce Wayne, and `root` like Batman. The difference is entirely a matter of constructed identity. Bruce Wayne can become Batman whenever he wants and do almost anything, but he will always be Bruce Wayne under the mask. Still, Batman is more who he really is--the Bruce Wayne persona is a contrivance that shields him from the consequences of being Batman. By presenting as Wayne in everyday life, he can often protect himself and his loved ones from his own mistakes, flaws in the system, and the malware of Gotham City.

Answer (score 4):

No such thing as a dumb question ;)

I hope this clarifies things a bit:

In Ubuntu, two different types of user accounts may be made: *standard* accounts and *administrator* accounts. The difference between the two: a standard account is not allowed to make any important changes to your system by attaining root access, whereas an administrator account may use their password to make changes as the root user. The Root user itself is one of the many users that the system has created and that you do not normally see or notice, and you can't login as it (by default, anyway). If you are logged into an administrator type account, you can become this Root user with the `sudo` command in a terminal, and you are able to type in your password in order to install software, make system changes, etc. If you are logged in as a standard user, you are unable to do any of that.

Comment: If the admin can become root by just running a command, can someone else/hacker run it remotely and become root user ?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName They need to already be logged in remotely as one of the other users to be able to run `sudo`

Comment: @FirstNameLastName also sudo asks for an accountname and password before giving root access.

Comment: @Destrictor - yes it does. in fact, that is what confused me. I am inside a admin account and put the admin password to login to root. when the password and username is the same for admin and root, why have two accounts ?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName the main reason you need to enter the password when using sudo is for logging. This is mainly for security reasons (something happened and your IT department is finding out who/what/where)

Comment: @Destrictor if one had an administrator account and one was up to no good, one could use sudo to do mischief and use sudo again to alter the logs.  This could be countered by logging to a WORM drive.

Answer (score 3):

In All Linux systems To do any changes to the system we need to be authenticated as root user and as well as to apply all changes we need to be root user.

Normal users cant apply the changes system wide.This is the advantage with Linux as compare with the windows.

If any attack done then that will stem up to only that area in Linux/Unix system because to attack or to modify remaining areas It need root permissions but in Windows if one place got attacked means the whole system will get affected.

That's why only in many questions if any user placed for no prompt for root password, then we will warn him as this is not recommended under security circumstances and leave choice upto them.

If you want to turn into a root user ,sudo can help you.

```
sudo -i
```

If you would like launch application as root user then you can sudo .

```
sudo <app_name>
```

It always a Better to run the system as non-root user.

Answer (score 3):

The account created during installation *is an administrator account*.

In Ubuntu, root account has no password and as a consequence, you **can not** login as the `root` user. There are ways to circumvent this, but this is the default setting.

An Administrator account in Ubuntu means that the user is added to the group `sudo`, which makes the account eligible to gain previleges temporarily using the `sudo` command. PolicyKit can request privilege escalation by prompting 'Administrator' password. (You need to select a administrator user, and give that account's password.)

#### To confirm that these are true:

- Open a terminal and attempt to update software package index. `apt-get update` is the command used to do it and this *requires* to be run as root. It works only when you either login as root, or execute it as root by using privilege escalations. An administrator can run `sudo apt-get update` by authenticating to the `sudo` mechanism which allows commands to be run as any user. A standard user will not be allowed to do this.
- Open User accounts from System Settings and attempt to add a new user. The protection mechanism used there is the PolicyKit. Administrators will be allowed to authenticate and escalate privileges but standard users will be blocked. It requires an 'administrator' password to proceed.

#### Here is how you check if your account is administrator or not:

- Open User accounts from System settings.
- Select your user account in the left column.
- You should see `Administrator` under the account name in both panes for administrator accounts and `Standard` for normal users.

Answer (score 2):

No.

the user you log in to Ubuntu with, is not the admin user
(the admin user in Linux terminology is called root)

Comment: This is misleading at best. The non-root user created during installation *is* an administrator. Not root, but an administrator (meaning, mainly, that they can perform actions as `root` with `sudo` and PolicyKit).

Comment: @EliahKagan - ok, then what is the difference between administrator and root accounts ? I am new to linux and also to computer science, so please bear with me.

Comment: @EliahKagan Not really, that's just trying to apply Windows terminology to linux.  `sudo` access can be limited by what program you're trying to run as root, which makes it a lot fuzzier.

Comment: @FirstNameLastName There is a user that is actually named "root" (usually; I've heard it can be changed, but I don't know how).  It has access to everything.

Comment: @Izkata [No, *administrator* has a specific meaning in Ubuntu.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YxZw5.png) It's simply *entirely incorrect* to say that the user account created during installation is not an administrator. As for allowing specific commands to run as `root` with `sudo`, that's irrelevant. Administrators can run *any* command as `root` with `sudo`. By default, no others can run any commands as `root` (or any other user) with `sudo`. Also, `sudo` is just one mechanism to perform actions as root--what people tend to think is `sudo` is actually often PolicyKit, these days.