# How to get administrator rights?

Tags: permissions, administration

I am the administrator and only user of my laptop with a new installation of 14.04.  I created a bootable USB and when it is used I find this file "PRJ_20071023" that I can not read or delete. I get a message that I do not have permission to access or delete the file.  How can I get around this limitation.  Although I have an administrator account, I appear to have no administrator rights.

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make my main user an administrator, just like in Windows XP?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/507900/how-can-i-make-my-main-user-an-administrator-just-like-in-windows-xp)

Comment: @Akiva It seems this is really asking how to access the files, not how to run with elevated privileges (i.e., as/like root) all the time.

Comment: I agree. The question needs an edit though to clarify that.