# who is the root user in Ubuntu

Tags: root

Who is the `root` user in Ubuntu  or on any Linux based distribution? Is by default the `root`password for every system running Ubuntu is same.Many documents over WEB supports not to enable `root` login manually or Graphically?as it has been said that let all applications should run on User level or with Administrative accounts only?

Comment: Also related: [How to NOT become a root user? Are administrators root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245201/how-to-not-become-a-root-user-are-administrators-root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who is the root user in Ubuntu or on any Linux based distribution?

The user having the real user id of `0` is the `root` user. You can check UID by `grep "root" /etc/passwd` or more precisely `grep "root" /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3` .

> Is by default the root password for every system running Ubuntu is
>   same?

By default the `root` account is disabled in Ubuntu (you can [enable it](https://askubuntu.com/a/44419), although it is not recommended), you can use `sudo` to impersonate `root`.

> Many documents over WEB supports not to enable root login manually as
>   it has been said that let all applications should run on User level or
>   with Administrative accounts only?

[Thats logical](https://askubuntu.com/q/16178).