# Is it considered good practice to avoid using `sudo su`?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, password, root

The root password is disabled by default so nobody can directly log into the root account.

However I can still log into root another way by doing `sudo su` and entering my own password, given that I am a member of the `sudo` group in `/etc/group` (as far as I know this is the only necessary condition).

Is this considered a bad practice to "backdoor" my way into the root account by using `sudo su`? Is it something to be avoided, and instead rely on using `sudo command` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is [good practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) to avoid performing more actions as root than you need to.** `sudo` facilitates this by allowing you to run individual commands as root [without having to log in as root](https://askubuntu.com/a/617767/22949) and without *needing* an interactive root shell for tasks you would otherwise not run a shell to do. But `sudo su` is not a "[backdoor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backdoor_(computing))," it is simply a somewhat less elegant way to do what `sudo` is designed to allow you to do with `sudo -s`. [Similarly](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2012-April/004960.html), `sudo -i` is the more elegant way to achieve what `sudo su -` would get you: a simulated *initial login shell* whose environment is like what you would get if you could log in as root on the command line. See [`man sudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sudo.8.html).

**Therefore it comes down to *when* you choose to run an interactive root shell and *how* you choose to use it.** If you're using it to avoid having to bother deciding whether or not to run commands as root, that would be bad. If you find you are running many commands in it that don't require root privileges, then you should consider running those commands in a non-privileged shell instead, or reconsider if you really need a root shell at all. But there is nothing fundamentally wrong with using a root shell.

With or without opening a root shell, it is possible to use `sudo` in a way that harms your security. For example, please don't run Firefox or LibreOffice with `sudo`. The potential problems with running a root shell are mostly that you may end up performing actions as root unnecessarily, and in the course  of doing so might make mistakes that are far more harmful when root does them. Therefore it is not sufficient to decide, "I'll just avoid this issue entirely by not running a root shell." It's quite reasonable to avoid running root shells, but that blanket choice still does not remove the need to be mindful when you *do* use `sudo`.

---

The [Ubuntu help wiki page about `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) lists [nine benefits of using `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Benefits_of_using_sudo). **Most but not all** of these benefits apply fully to the use of `sudo` to open a shell, provided you are as careful of what you do in that shell as you are of what you do in individual commands you use with `sudo`. These are the exceptions--benefits of `sudo` **that you do not fully enjoy** when you  use it to open a root shell:

> 4. sudo adds a log entry of the command(s) run (in `/var/log/auth.log`). If you mess up, you can go back and see what commands were run.

See also [**bodhi.zazen's answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/962024/22949). The one command you use to open that shell is still logged to `auth.log`, but the commands you run *from* it aren't.

> 9. The authentication automatically expires after a short time (which can be set to as little as desired or 0); so if you walk away from the terminal after running commands as root using sudo, you will not be leaving a root terminal open indefinitely.

Although you should always be mindful of what commands you (or someone else) might run while you have an active `sudo` timestamp, using an interactive root shell elevates this need, because any command run in it until you exit the shell will be run as root without prompting you for a password.

In addition, one of the benefits is *slightly* attenuated when you use a root shell, though still largely intact:

> 3. It avoids the "I can do anything" interactive login by default. You will be prompted for a password before major changes can happen, which should make you think about the consequences of what you are doing.

If you were to pretend you were root and had no other user account while using this root shell, then of course you would lose this benefit entirely. However, when you run `sudo -s`, `sudo -i`, or another command that gives you a shell, you had already been in a non-root login (unless you do it from recovery mode or have enabled root logins), so this temptation is much easier to avoid.

That is, if you were logging in as root, you would likely do so in *anticipation* of needing to do things only root can do. With a root shell you start yourself, it is less tempting to use it unnecessarily because, for just a few commands, it's actually *easier* to run them individually with `sudo`--and because you're already logged in as yourself.

And there is also one benefit of `sudo` that people sometimes think is lost when one runs a root shell *but they are completely mistaken to think so*:

> 7. sudo can be setup with a much more fine-grained security policy.

Running a root shell does not decrease this benefit at all, because it can only be done by users who are configured to be able to perform any actions, and thus does not let you do anything you couldn't do before by design. (This is another reason, [deeper than the mere presence of the `-s` and `-i` options](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2012-April/004960.html), that `sudo su` not really similar to a backdoor at all.)

Technically, it could *also* be done by users whom you have configured in `sudoers` to "only" be allowed to run root shells and nothing else! But that would be a very foolish configuration, since if a user can run a shell as root, they can perform any action as root. (You would have to undertake specific action to create this silly and dangerous situation for a user you intend to practically restrict.) There are many commands that are unexpectedly dangerous to allow any not-fully-trusted user to run as root--more than just shells and text editors. Any command that will generate an output file at a location the user specifies can be used to carry out a [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) attack if it can be run by a user you do not intend to already be able to do whatever they choose as root.

---

If you choose to run an interactive shell as root, be very careful. Consider if this really helps you, and if you will end up doing more as root than you intend. Remember that, even on a system with just one human user, even though you can do bad things like deleting all your personal files *without* using `sudo` at all, performing actions as root does not merely make it possible for you to harm your Ubuntu system in more ways. **If you do things as root that don't need to be done as root, you make it harder to reason  about what harms are possible (or have occurred).**

With that said, there are numerous common *alternatives* to using a root shell that are equally or more dangerous. For example, you might run a command without `sudo`, but it fails since you needed to run it as root, then use [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) to run it with `sudo`. But are you sure you ran the right command? With sophisticated history expansion constructs like hoping `sudo !f` will run your last `foo` command, mistakes are extremely easy. But even with the basic `!!` to run the last command, mistakes happen. If you ran `foo; bar` and then run `sudo !!`, is it `foo` or `bar` that runs as root? If you're going to use history expansion with `sudo`, it's not enough to know the answer--you have to succeed at keeping it mind every time you do it.

For most situations, the way I recommend you avoid retyping when adding `sudo` to commands is simply to press the <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> until you get to the command you needed to run `sudo`, press <kbd>Home</kbd> to get the beginning of the command, *read the command carefully to ensure it's really what you want to do*, then type `sudo` and a space. If the situations that tempt you to run a root shell--or to use more dangerous methods--are situations where it's reasonably convenient to just do that, then you don't need a root shell. And if you find yourself forgetting to type `sudo` (as many of us sometimes do, myself included), remember that you might also be forgetting other things, things that would make you glad you forgot to run the command as root.

Answer (score 3):

You question is more an opinion than anything else.

IMO best practice is to use sudo every time as sudo will log your commands, while sudo su will not (once you are root).

If that is too tedious I suggest `sudo -i` for better isolation between user and root accounts (environmental variables)

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells

Comment: Where is sudo logged? `/var/log/auth.log`? Root activity is unlogged?

Comment: From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Advantages_and_Disadvantages "4. sudo adds a log entry of the command(s) run (in /var/log/auth.log). If you mess up, you can go back and see what commands were run."

Comment: But when you say sudo su does not log (because you are root) does this mean root activity is not logged anywhere?

Comment: depends. root activity after running sudo su is not logged in system logs at all. It could be logged in .bash_history but not always.